# Java, weka LibSVM does not predict correctly

Tags: java, machine-learning, regression, weka, libsvm

I'm using LibSVM with the weka in my java code. I am trying to do a regression. Below is my code,

```
public static void predict() {

    try {
        DataSource sourcePref1 = new DataSource("train_pref2new.arff");
        Instances trainData = sourcePref1.getDataSet();

        DataSource sourcePref2 = new DataSource("testDatanew.arff");
        Instances testData = sourcePref2.getDataSet();

        if (trainData.classIndex() == -1) {
            trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes() - 2);
        }

        if (testData.classIndex() == -1) {
            testData.setClassIndex(testData.numAttributes() - 2);
        }

        LibSVM svm1 = new LibSVM();

        String options = ("-S 3 -K 2 -D 3 -G 1000.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1");
        String[] optionsArray = options.split(" ");
        svm1.setOptions(optionsArray);

        svm1.buildClassifier(trainData);

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i++) {

            double pref1 = svm1.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));                
            System.out.println("predicted value : " + pref1);

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But the predicted value I am getting from this code is different than the predicted value I am getting by using the Weka GUI.

**Example:** 
Below is a single testing data that I have given for both java code and weka GUI.

[image]

The Java code predicted the value as **1.9064516129032265** while the Weka GUI's predicted value is **10.043**. I am using the same training data set and the same parameters for both Java code and Weka GUI.

I hope you understand my question.Could any one tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong algorithm to perform SVM regression. LibSVM is used for classification. The one you want is [SMOreg](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMOreg.html), which a specific SVM for regression.

Below is a complete example that shows how to use SMOreg using both the Weka Explorer GUI as well as the Java API. For data, I will use the `cpu.arff` data file that comes with the Weka distribution. Note that I'll use this file for both training and test, but ideally you would have separate data sets.

**Using the Weka Explorer GUI**

1. Open the WEKA Explorer GUI, click on the `Preprocess` tab, click on `Open File`, and then open the `cpu.arff` file that should be in your Weka distribution. On my system, the file is under `weka-3-8-1/data/cpu.arff`. The Explorer window should look like the following:

[image: Weka Explorer - Choosing the file]

2. Click on the `Classify` tab. It should really be called "Prediction" because you can do both classification and regression here. Under `Classifier`, click on `Choose` and then select `weka` --> `classifiers` --> `functions` --> `SMOreg`, as shown below.

[image: Weka Explorer - Choosing the regression algorithm]

3. Now build the regression model and evaluate it. Under `Test Options` choose `Use training set` so that our the training set is used for testing as well (as I mentioned above, this is not the ideal methodology). Now press `Start`, and the result should look like the following:

[image: Weka Explorer - Results from testing]

Make a note of the RMSE value (74.5996). We'll revisit that in the Java code implementation.

**Using the Java API**

Below is a complete Java program that uses the Weka API to replicate the results shown earlier in the Weka Explorer GUI.

```
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class Tester {

    /**
     * Builds a regression model using SMOreg, the SVM for regression, and 
     * evaluates it with the Evalution framework.
     */
    public void buildAndEvaluate(String trainingArff, String testArff) throws Exception {

        System.out.printf("buildAndEvaluate() called.\n");

        // Load the training and test instances.
        Instances trainingInstances = DataSource.read(trainingArff);
        Instances testInstances = DataSource.read(testArff);

        // Set the true value to be the last field in each instance.
        trainingInstances.setClassIndex(trainingInstances.numAttributes()-1);
        testInstances.setClassIndex(testInstances.numAttributes()-1);

        // Build the SMOregression model.
        SMOreg smo = new SMOreg();
        smo.buildClassifier(trainingInstances);

        // Use Weka's evaluation framework.
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainingInstances);
        eval.evaluateModel(smo, testInstances);

        // Print the options that were used in the ML algorithm.
        String[] options = smo.getOptions();
        System.out.printf("Options used:\n");
        for (String option : options) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", option);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n\n");

        // Print the algorithm details.
        System.out.printf("Algorithm:\n %s\n", smo.toString());

        // Print the evaluation results.
        System.out.printf("%s\n", eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n=====\n", false));
    }

    /**
     * Builds a regression model using SMOreg, the SVM for regression, and 
     * tests each data instance individually to compute RMSE.
     */
    public void buildAndTestEachInstance(String trainingArff, String testArff) throws Exception {

        System.out.printf("buildAndTestEachInstance() called.\n");

        // Load the training and test instances.
        Instances trainingInstances = DataSource.read(trainingArff);
        Instances testInstances = DataSource.read(testArff);

        // Set the true value to be the last field in each instance.
        trainingInstances.setClassIndex(trainingInstances.numAttributes()-1);
        testInstances.setClassIndex(testInstances.numAttributes()-1);

        // Build the SMOregression model.
        SMOreg smo = new SMOreg();
        smo.buildClassifier(trainingInstances);

        int numTestInstances = testInstances.numInstances();

        // This variable accumulates the squared error from each test instance.
        double sumOfSquaredError = 0.0;

        // Loop over each test instance.
        for (int i = 0; i < numTestInstances; i++) {

            Instance instance = testInstances.instance(i);

            double trueValue = instance.value(testInstances.classIndex());
            double predictedValue = smo.classifyInstance(instance);

            // Uncomment the next line to see every prediction on the test instances.
            //System.out.printf("true=%10.5f, predicted=%10.5f\n", trueValue, predictedValue);

            double error = trueValue - predictedValue;
            sumOfSquaredError += (error * error);
        }

        // Print the RMSE results.
        double rmse = Math.sqrt(sumOfSquaredError / numTestInstances);
        System.out.printf("RMSE = %10.5f\n", rmse);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        Tester classify = new Tester();
        classify.buildAndEvaluate("../weka-3-8-1/data/cpu.arff", "../weka-3-8-1/data/cpu.arff");
        classify.buildAndTestEachInstance("../weka-3-8-1/data/cpu.arff", "../weka-3-8-1/data/cpu.arff");
    }
}
```

I've written two functions that train an SMOreg model and evaluate the model by running prediction on the training data.

- `buildAndEvaluate()` evaluates the model by using the Weka
  `Evaluation` framework to run a suite of tests to get the exact same
  results as the Explorer GUI. Notably, it produces an RMSE value.
- `buildAndTestEachInstance()` evaluates the model by explicitly
  looping over each test instance, making a prediction, computing the
  error, and computing an overall RMSE. Note that this RMSE matches
  the one from `buildAndEvaluate()`, which in turn matches the one
  from the Explorer GUI.

Below is the result from compiling and running the program.

```
prompt> javac -cp weka.jar Tester.java

prompt> java -cp .:weka.jar Tester

buildAndEvaluate() called.
Options used:
-C 1.0 -N 0 -I weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -T 0.001 -V -P 1.0E-12 -L 0.001 -W 1 -K weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -E 1.0 -C 250007 

Algorithm:
 SMOreg

weights (not support vectors):
 +       0.01   * (normalized) MYCT
 +       0.4321 * (normalized) MMIN
 +       0.1847 * (normalized) MMAX
 +       0.1175 * (normalized) CACH
 +       0.0973 * (normalized) CHMIN
 +       0.0235 * (normalized) CHMAX
 -       0.0168



Number of kernel evaluations: 21945 (93.081% cached)

Results
=====

Correlation coefficient                  0.9044
Mean absolute error                     31.7392
Root mean squared error                 74.5996
Relative absolute error                 33.0908 %
Root relative squared error             46.4953 %
Total Number of Instances              209     

buildAndTestEachInstance() called.
RMSE =   74.59964
```

Comment: Actually Libsvm has 2 svm types for regression, nu-SVR and epsilon-SVR. I can decide which svm type to use by defining -S parameter of the algorithm. In my code I have used the epsilon-SVR(-S 3). But your code really helped me to find the error in my code. setClassIndex is wrong in my code. I used your code and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.